# Is it possible to automate variable creation in a for loop in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I was wondering if there is a nice way to use a loop in order to create and assign variables. I usually catch the objects in a list, but it would be nice to access each by a variable name.
For example I want to automatically create several machine learning models with different parameters and assign each model to variable model_1,model_2 and so on.
something that could look like this:

```
for i,parameter in enum(list_of_parameters):
    model_ + i = model_generator_function(parameter)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Variable variable names are a bad idea. A really bad idea. Put your data in a `list` or in a `dict`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. Found it also here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thing is, you cannot generate the name of the variables at runtime, so you must hold them somewhere. I suggest using a dictionary.
Try to do something like this:

```
models = {}

for parameter in list_of_parameters :
    for i in range(len(list_of_parameters)) :
        models[f"model_{i}"] = model_generator_function(parameter)
```

You can access your variables easily (`models[model_name]`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dictionary` where you can create keys dynamically.
Try to do something like the following:

```
data = {}

for i, param in enum(list_of_params):
        data['model_{}'.format(i)] = model_generator_function(param)
```

Answer (score 0):

A dict may be useful, creating keys like "model_0", "model_1" etc. is somewhat awkward tough.
If you actually just have a list of models, you can just as well put them in a list:

```
models = list()
for parameter in list_of_parameters :
    models.append(model_generator_function(parameter))
```

Or shorter:

```
models = [model_generator_function(p)
          for p in list_of_parameters]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've done so far. But for me a dict might be the better solution, since it is a lot easier to keep track of the models, e.g. what parameters were used.